# Upgrade Flutter debug build on device (using VSCode)

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code

I have an app that is just for personal use. I can run it from VSCode directly (just run & debug). It saves its data onto its assigned "disk space" on the device. However, when I close the app and restart it (no longer connected to my dev PC), it starts up an old version of the app - obviously the one I last really installed on the device.

The only way I know to have the latest version on the device would be to deinstall it, then install it via devPC. Unfortunately, this deletes the local files of the app.

Is there a way to upgrade the installed version directly from the dev PC? I think it is possible to manually install the newest apk after I built it, but is there a way as easy as "run & debug", with the only difference that the latest version of the app starts when I restart the app?

Answer (score 0):

There are no option to upgrade the app locally from PC. Every time you connect the phone and press Run & Debug, it will rebuild the app again.

In order to persist your data through different app versions, you should consider integrating some simple backend structure to your app.

You can think of creating a database which will provide you data every time you open the app. One easy option you can try is to integrate the Cloud Firestore in your app. You can follow [this tutorial](https://medium.com/47billion/how-to-use-firebase-with-flutter-e4a47a7470ce) here to understand the implementation and feel free to ask if you need any further support.